# How do I call a function that is member of a class, from another function?

Tags: c++, mfc

So I have the following:

```
INT CMainFrm::load(Cstring path)
{

}

extern "C"
{
   EXPORT void fileLoad(CString filePath)
   {
      CMainFrm *cmf = new CMainFrm();
      cmf->load(filePath);
   }
}
```

Both are located in mainfrm.cpp.

`fileLoad()`  is called from a dll and that works fine.
When I try to call `load()` from inside `fileload()` it gives me unhandled exception...I also tried calling it using an instance of `CMainFrm` but the result is the same. Any suggestion on how to do this properly?

Comment: Does `CMainFrm` inherit from a MFC class ?

Comment: @Blacktempel `class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWnd`

Comment: Did you call `Create(...)` ?

Comment: @Blacktempel where exactly?

Comment: In your code after allocating memory for `CMainFrm` && before `cmf->load`

Comment: @Blacktempel I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the CMainFrm object that already exists. (It is created at program startup.) MFC provides a global function that you can call to get a pointer to this main window: AfxGetMainWnd(). You may cast the returned value to CMainFrm* and use it to call load.

Comment: can you please provide an example of how it should look?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out and it worked. You gave me the solution to a half a day problem in one line of code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You must call [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4y17z36a.aspx) for dynamically allocated/created MFC classes ([CWnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yhc9kx4.aspx)), otherwise your `m_hWnd` will not be valid and your window not created.
Most likely you will get a exception.

Comment: yes but I'm not trying to create a new window, all that the function does is load a file into the bigger program and all this happens in background with no window creation. The functions' main purpose is to manipulate the file. I've looked over the example from msdn but didn't seem to help.